# How do I deploy a artifact with maven layout using REST API?

Tags: artifactory

I can do a normal deploy using the below command

```
curl -i -X PUT -u $artifactoryUser:$artifactoryPassword -T /path/to/file/file.zip http://localhost/artifactory/simple/repo/groupId/artifactId/version/file.zip
```

However, this will not resolve or update maven layout on the artifact. Is there a way I can upload without using the artifactory-maven plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by "not resolve or update maven layout"?

Comment: This is not creating "Dependency Declaration" for Maven or any other build tool. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: you mean you don't see the snippet in the UI?
Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: can you post the actual path you used? if you used a valid Maven layout you should see the dependency deceleration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this question I had posted.

Syntax Used:

```
curl -i -X PUT -K $CURLPWD "http://localhost/artifactory/$REPO/$groupId/$artifactId/$versionId/$artifactId-$versionId.$fileExt"
```

Ended up writing a script so that md5 & sha1 values are uploaded with the file, or else, I had to go in Artifactory and fix it manually.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
        echo "Please check the Usage of the Script, there were no enough parameters supplied."
        echo "Usage: ArtifactoryUpload.sh localFilePath Repo GroupID ArtifactID VersionID"
        exit 1
}

if [ -z "$5" ]; then
        usage
fi

localFilePath="$1"
REPO="$2"
groupId="$3"
artifactId="$4"
versionId="$5"

ARTIFAC=http://localhost/artifactory

if [ ! -f "$localFilePath" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: local file $localFilePath does not exists!"
        exit 1
fi

which md5sum || exit $?
which sha1sum || exit $?

md5Value="`md5sum "$localFilePath"`"
md5Value="${md5Value:0:32}"

sha1Value="`sha1sum "$localFilePath"`"
sha1Value="${sha1Value:0:40}"

fileName="`basename "$localFilePath"`"
fileExt="${fileName##*.}"

echo $md5Value $sha1Value $localFilePath
echo "INFO: Uploading $localFilePath to $targetFolder/$fileName"

curl -i -X PUT -K $CURLPWD \
-H "X-Checksum-Md5: $md5Value" \
-H "X-Checksum-Sha1: $sha1Value" \
-T "$localFilePath" \
"$ARTIFAC/$REPO/$groupId/$artifactId/$versionId/$artifactId-$versionId.$fileExt"
```

Comment: I understand its pretty old, but tried without reading the code and ended up deploying sources jar as a binary jar. That's something one needs to be cautious about. Rerunning the script with binary jar fixes the issue on artifactory.